# Was the music teacher part of the plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, mrs-miracle

In the Hallmark Christmas movie "Mrs. Miracle," was the music teacher falling off the stage part of Emily Merkle's plan to get Reba and Seth together, or was it more coincidental?

Reba's friend works at the school, and the music teacher's accident creates the perfect opportunity to get Reba involved with Seth and his kids.

So was this accident planned, or did Emily have another idea in store, and then just used the teacher's fall to her advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a definitive answer, this is a film with religious themes. Hallmark produced a [study guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fflash.sonypictures.com%2Fdownloads%2Fhomevideo%2Faffirmfilms%2Fmrsmiracle_guide.pdf&ei=ksyNVIOyAYi1yASLgoKwDA&usg=AFQjCNE34u6XNLgw82YbFXRMIQcyOHGcqw&sig2=k_0ZBtpRS7l24Idfjwc1PQ&bvm=bv.81828268,d.aWw) for the film, tying scripture to the plot and identifying the themes of grief, forgiveness, and service. There is an underlying belief in a benevolent God, and that does not seem compatible with the idea that an angelic force like Mrs. Miracle could randomly hurt one person in order to help another (unless of course falling off the stage had a spiritual benefit for the music teacher as well, which is not part of the story).

I think more likely it was either an accident that Mrs. Miracle chose to use (and in the absence of this accident, she would have chosen another vehicle), or being of some mysterious angelic realm, Mrs. Miracle knew the accident was going to happen ahead of time and landed in this place at this time to use it to help Seth heal.